# how can I FIND hcf and lcm of number with time complexity O(log n ) by using vectors

Tags: c++, time-complexity, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

In this program,we need to find hcf and lcm of a number and must use vector for it and time complexity should be O(log n) and using c++.

```
class Solution 
{
  public:
    
    vector<long long> lcmAndGcd(long long A , long long B)
    {
         
        long long min,hcf,lcm;
        // code here
        if(A<B)
        min=A;
        else
        min=B;
        for(long long i=min;i>=1;i--)
        {
            if((A%i==0)&&(B%i==0))
            {
             hcf=i;
            
             break;
            }
        }
        lcm=(A*B)/hcf;
        vector<long long> v;
         v.push_back(lcm);
       v.push_back(hcf);
       
        return v;
    }
    
};
```

I did this but I am not able to do it with time complexity O(logN)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: A side note: in `if((A%i==0)&&(B%i==0))` only `hcf=i;` is a part of the `if` body. Maybe you meant to enclose the `if`s body with `{}`.

Comment: @kiner_shah is there any other method also? other than this algoritham

Comment: @wohlstad thank you for finding the error ,I have corrected it. but still I am getting time limit exceeded.

Comment: @Anonymous007, I just found this random algorithm by Google search. I would use the answer given by BenjaminBuch, i.e. std::lcm and std::gcd.

Answer (score 2):

The C++17 standard library provides [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) and [`std::lcm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm). I strongly advise against implementing them yourself. This leads to slow, error-prone and unnecessarily complicated code.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::int64_t> lcm_and_gcd(std::int64_t const a, std::int64_t const b) {
    return {std::lcm(a, b), std::gcd(a, b)};
}

int main() {
    auto const data = lcm_and_gcd(25, 30);
    std::cout << "lcm(25, 30) = " << data[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "gcd(25, 30) = " << data[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: okay! there is a division method by using recursion which we can apply ,but I am not able to implement it in form of vectors.

Comment: @Anonymous007 I created a vector with the two results as elements as you did in your question code. If that's not what you want, than please update you question. If you need an implementation on base of vector for a homework, than state that as part of your question please.

Comment: thank you, I understood the code. Just for clarification I want to know that can we do it without using library function and time complexity O(log N)?

Comment: @Anonymous007 This is a pure educational question. You can use ChatGPT as a good starting point for such purpose. I asked "Write me a C++ implementation for the greatest common divisor with complexity O(log n)." which gave me a recursive Implementation. Asking further "Replace the recursion with std::vector." gave me what you asked for. Chatbots do not guarantee correct answers! However, they are perfectly suitable as a support and introduction ;-)

Comment: On GitHub you can check [Microsofts implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e066dc/stl/inc/numeric#L594), but it is not easy to read.